# Insert line number in a file

Tags: linux, sed

Would like to insert line number at specific location in file 
e.g.

```
apple 
ball
```

should be

```
(1) apple 
(2) ball
```

Using command
`sed '/./=' <FileName>| sed '/./N; s/\n/ /'`

It generates

```
1 Apple
2 Ball
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** This should be an easy task for `awk`.

```
awk '{print "("FNR") "$0}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With pure `sed` as per OP's attempt try:

```
sed '=' Input_file | sed 'N; s/^/(/;s/\n/) /'
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with perl instead:

```
perl -ne 'print "($.) $_"' foo.txt
```

If you want to modify the file in-place instead of just printing out the numbered lines on standard output:

```
perl -ni -e 'print "($.) $_"' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Many ways are there to insert line numbers in a file**

some of them are :-

1.**Using cat command**
cat -n file.txt > newfile.txt

2.**Using nl command**
nl -b a file.txt

Comment: Do either of those produce OP's desired output format?

Comment: Yes it gives line number in a file to each new line

Comment: Where are the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Awk and perl both are very usefull and powerfull. But if, like me, you are reluctant to learn yet another programming language, you can complete this task with the bash commands you probably know already.

With bash you can

- increment a sequence number `n`: `$((++n))`
- read all lines from a file `foo` into a variable `l`: `while read -r l;do ...;done <foo`, where the option `-r` serves to treat backslashes as just characters.
- print formatted output to a line: `printf "plain text %i %s\n" number string`

Now suppose you want to enclose your sequence number in parentheses, and format them to 8 digits with leading zeroes, then you combine all this to get:

```
n=0;while read -r l;do printf "(%08i) %s\n" $((++n)) "$l";done <foo >numberedfoo
```

Note that you do not need to initialize the variable `n` to use it as a sequence number further on. But if you experiment with this command a few times without reinitializing `n`, your lines will be numbered from where your previous try stopped incrementing.

Finally, if you don't like the C-like formatting syntax of printf, just use plain echo, and leave the formatting to bash variable expansion. Here is how to format a number like in the command above (do type a space before the `-`, and a `;` before the `echo`) :

```
nformat="0000000$n"; echo "(${nformat: -8}) ...";
```